# Libreoffice reduce formula line space

Tags: libreoffice

Here I got a text in libreoffice, third line has a mathematical formula which has added a lot of horizontal space above and below its line (third line). how can reduce the horizontal space in this line?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer, it's just enough to set a fixed line space, not single or double or proportional.
Just right click on the paragraph and then select paragraph from menu and in idents and spacing tab, Line spacing > Fixed and then set a number for line height.